# Can we get Smart Contract address by Token Name

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, erc20, ethereumclassic

I want to get smart contract information by token name as Etherscan does but with my private network.

According to web3 doc, If I need to get any information related to Smart Contract, I first need to have a smart contract address and ABI. But when writing Smart Contract I don't have the command to store it in my database.

**My main goal is I need to create an exact copy of explorer as Etherscan and bscscan.com**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is your private network, you have private tokens. I assume you have an ERC-20 token smart contract you are going to deploy.

Just modify your token smart contract to [emit an event](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12950/what-are-solidity-events-and-how-they-are-related-to-topics-and-logs) in a constructor, like `TokenCreated(string name, string symbol)`. Then you can fetch this event list from your JSON-RPC node.

> My main goal is I need to create an exact copy of explorer as Etherscan and bscscan.com

EtherScan was built by an expert team over a period of six years. If you want feature parity with EtherScan, you are unlikely to accomplish it working solo.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Mikko Ohtamaa for your reply.

I will give it a try.

Comment: I have one more question, how can I get a private key from UTC Keystore file of my generated address in python

Comment: I suggest for a new question you actually post a new question, not a comment.